# emmip (emmeans) with quadratic term

Tags: r, glm, emmeans

Is it possible to plot with emmip the marginal (log odds) means from a geeglm model when you have a quadratic term? I have repeated measures data and the model fits better with a treatment x time squared term in addition to an interaction term with linear time.

I just want to be able to visualise the predicted curve in the data. If it's possible I don't know how to specify it. I've tried:

```
mod3 <- geeglm(outcome ~ treatment*time + treatment*time_sq, data = dat, id = id, family = "binomial", corstr = "exchangeable"))
mod3a.rg <- ref_grid(mod3, at = list(time = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), time_sq = c(1,4,9,16,25,36)))
emmip(mod3a.rg, treatment ~ time)
```

Comment: DO NOT use an extra variable `time_sq` in the model. Use `poly(time, degree=2)` instead. Then use `emmip(..., at = list(time = 1:6))`

Comment: That solves it - thank you

Comment: Good. Even when not plotting, it ‘s really important that each covariate be represented by only one predictor, because EMMs are typically computed at the average of each covariate. The average `time` and the average `time_sq` likely form an incongruous combination.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your mod3 is including your quadratic term correctly (hard to tell since you did not include reproducible code). This will let you include your squared term for time correctly:

```
mod3 <- geeglm(outcome ~ treatment*time + treatment*I(time^2), data =
dat, id = id, family = "binomial", corstr = "exchangeable"))
```

The add `plotit = TRUE` to your call to `emmip()`:

```
emmip(mod3a.rg, treatment ~ time, plotit = TRUE)
```

Here's a simple reproducible example with the savings dataset in the MASS, faraway package for comparison

```
library(MASS)
data(savings, package="faraway") 

#fit model with polynomial term
mod <- lm(sr ~ ddpi+I(ddpi^2))
summary(mod)
```

The summary produces this output, note the additonal coefficient for your quadratic term

```
> Call: lm(formula = sr ~ ddpi + I(ddpi^2), data = savings)
> 
> Residuals:
>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
> -8.5601 -2.5612  0.5546  2.5735  7.8080 
> 
> Coefficients:
>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
>(Intercept)  5.13038    1.43472   3.576 0.000821 ***
>ddpi         1.75752    0.53772   3.268 0.002026 ** 
>I(ddpi^2)   -0.09299    0.03612  -2.574 0.013262 *  
> --- Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> 
> Residual standard error: 4.079 on 47 degrees of freedom Multiple
> R-squared:  0.205,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1711  F-statistic: 6.059 on
> 2 and 47 DF,  p-value: 0.004559
```

If you don't enclose the quadratic term with `I()` your summary will only include the term for ddpi.

```
mod2 <- lm(sr ~ ddpi+ddpi^2)
summary(mod2)
```

produces the following summary with a coefficient only for ddpi

```
> lm(formula = sr ~ ddpi + ddpi^2, data = savings)
> 
> Residuals:
>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
> -8.5535 -3.7349  0.9835  2.7720  9.3104 
> 
> Coefficients:
>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)     
>(Intercept)   7.8830     1.0110   7.797 4.46e-10 *** 
>ddpi          0.4758     0.2146   2.217   0.0314 *  
> --- Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> 
> Residual standard error: 4.311 on 48 degrees of freedom Multiple
> R-squared:  0.0929,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.074  F-statistic: 4.916 on
> 1 and 48 DF,  p-value: 0.03139
```

Comment: Thank you - but I don't understand how that helps me to make a plot.

Comment: @Lucas,I just updated my answer to include the flag to plot - also my answer was also trying to point out that you may not have been including the quadratic term correctly in your model.  You can read more about emmip options on the help page with the command ```?emmip```